# How to change the order of parameters on a component in schematic

Tags: altium, symbol, schematic, parameters

In my symbol library for my capacitor, the capacitance displays before the voltage rating. When I place it on a schematic, the voltage displays first. I want the capacitance to display first. How can I do this?

Symbol:
[image]

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: Really need to know how you've set these parameters up

Comment: In the schematic library I went to this component, the properties menu, and went down to where the parameters are and hit add parameter.

Comment: Why don't you try to change the order that you entered the parameters with?

Answer (score 1):

Our legacy method was to put 1_Value, 2_Voltage, ...it's working but if use dblib or svndblib to import parameters from external database, you have to change the name of your parameter title too.  It was the less effort changes we found to solve problem